# Problems with reading text and display in textboxs in c#

Tags: c#

My intention is using File.ReadAllText to read a text file line by line. After that, I will check each string array if it contains the keyword that I expected, I will take the whole string out and display it into a textbox. So here is my code :

```
        OpenFileDialog fopen = new OpenFileDialog();
        fopen.Filter = "(All type)|*.*";
        fopen.ShowDialog();
        if(fopen.FileName != "")
        {
            textBox1.Text = fopen.FileName;
            string save = fopen.FileName;
            string save1 = save.Split('.')[0];
            //string readtext = File.ReadAllText(save);
            //string[] readtext1 = readtext.Split('\n');
            string[] readline = File.ReadAllLines(save);
            int lines = readline.Count();
            textBox2.Text = readtext;

            for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++ )
            {
                if (readline[i].Contains("CPL"))
                {                    
                    int len = readline[i].Length;
                    textBox3.Text = readline[i].Substring(2, len - 4);
                    textBox3.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                }

            }
```

The problem is : if the input file look like

```
<>something<>
<>something1<>
<>something2<>
<>something3CPL<>
<>something4CPL<>
<>something5CPL<>
```

The output is always just the last string array. (here is something5CPL). 
What I expected is

```
something3CPL
something4CPL
something5CPL
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with my code?
Thank you.

Comment: On each iteration you are setting a new value. You probably meant to use `+=` inside `for`.

Comment: That is because `textBox3.Text = readline[i].Substring(2, len - 4);` replaces the existing text. you gotta use something like this: `textBox3.Text += readline[i].Substring(2, len - 4); + Environment.NewLine`

Comment: your code is doing what you asked for, what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning (overwriting) the text in the textbox each iteration, so it'll only hold the last value you get from the file:

```
textBox3.Text = readline[i].Substring(2, len - 4);
```

Instead, use the same technique (appending) as you did with the `Environment.Newline`:

```
textBox3.AppendText(readline[i].Substring(2, len - 4));
```

This will keep adding the new values onto the end of the textbox's existing text, as you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **append** the text each  instead of **setting** the text in each iteration:

```
textBox3.AppendText(readline[i].Substring(2, len - 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

May be in place of

```
textBox3.Text = readline[i].Substring(2, len - 4);
```

use

```
textBox3.Text += readline[i].Substring(2, len - 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

As a textbox you can't see the results vertically.

Anyway this is the solution:

```
    OpenFileDialog fopen = new OpenFileDialog();
    fopen.Filter = "(All type)|*.*";
    fopen.ShowDialog();
    if(fopen.FileName != "")
    {
        textBox1.Text = fopen.FileName;
        string save = fopen.FileName;
        string save1 = save.Split('.')[0];
        //string readtext = File.ReadAllText(save);
        //string[] readtext1 = readtext.Split('\n');
        string[] readline = File.ReadAllLines(save);
        int lines = readline.Count();
        textBox2.Text = readtext;

        for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++ )
        {
            if (readline[i].Contains("CPL"))
            {                    
                int len = readline[i].Length;
                textBox3.Text += (readline[i].Substring(2, len - 4) + " ");
            }

        }
```

Comment: [Multiline textboxes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12w624ff(v=vs.110).aspx) are quite commonly used, I thought.